# RecyclerView inside CoordinatorLayout,AppBarLayout Scrolling issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout, smooth-scrolling

I have this xml code in fragment:

```
<CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"                              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"                         android:layout_width="match_parent"                    android:layout_height="match_parent"                       android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"                      android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
     <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            app:elevation="0dp">
     <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
                android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
                app:statusBarScrim="@color/bestColor">
    <LinearLayout></LinearLayout> <!--this elements hide then appbar is collapsed-->
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
    <ImageButton>
     android:id="@+id/profile_header_trophies"
    </ImageButton><!-- this elements like a tab,visible if appbar collapsed-->
    </LinearLayout> 
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/profile_recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

in Java Class on Item set ClickListener:

```
@OnClick(R.id.profile_header_trophies)
    public void profile_header_trophies_clicked() {
        if (myProfile != null) {
            appBarLayout.setExpanded(false, false);
            if (myProfile.getBests().size() == 0) {
                profile_recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(3);
            } else {
                profile_recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(2 + 20);
                }
            }
```

When I click to **ImageButton**, my **RecyclerView** scrolls to position, everything looks fine.
But if I put finger on AppBarLayout section (ImageButton) which visible(sticky) on top, and drag to bottom I have a bad scrolling.
My appbar start expanded, while my Recycler have some elements on top (they are hidden when scrolled).

[image]

I think this problem is setting behavoir. Because if I scrolling recycler first, AppBar doesnt start expanding, while Recycler not rich top of elements.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Did you tried applying layout_behavouir on collabsing toolbar ??

Comment: What is the name of BottomTab library? It looks very nice.

Comment: @Thracian this is simple layout with own logick, ty

Comment: Hi did you find solution?

Comment: @NehaK find this answer help me. workaround: change root element to NestedScrollView, add recycler to it, and add to nestedscrollingEnabled = true to NestedScrollView (>21ApI) or use NestedScrollChildHelper for support libr

Comment: should I add header also in NestedScrollView?

Answer (score 5):

The bad scrolling once happened to me, it was happening because I was using `RecyclerView` inside another `RecyclerView`.

So when I try to scroll contents in the main `RecyclerView` it gave me this issue.

To resolve that issue I added this to `RecyclerView`:

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

For doing this in XML you can use:

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
```

Comment: What's worse, this is actually completely backwards. You should not have this, it will block the intended behaviour

Comment: This is correct way to making toolbar `scrollFlags` working in case of nested RecyclerViews (to make toolbar scroll working, place `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"` in nested RecyclerViews)

Answer (score 5):

with this, you tell it to "merge" the scrolling of the RecyclerView with the scrolling of its parent

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

if I well understood, you want to have the following scrolling behaviour:

- if you are scrolling by touching outside the RecyclerView, it collapses the AppBar
- if you are scrolling by touching inside it, it ignores the RecyclerView's scroll and collapses the AppBar, and once the AppBar is collapsed, it scrolls inside the RecyclerView

Could you confirm this is the desired behaviour please?

In such case, you may look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31361962/prevent-recyclerview-from-intercepting-scroll-touch-events), maybe it will help

Answer (score 0):

It can be tricky and there's a few things you need to have in order for this to work.

You should use `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"` in your `CollapsingToolbarLayout` instead of just `scroll`.

It's not clear where the tabs or buttons are in your XML layout, but if they are supposed to stay on screen then you need to `pin` them, so you would use `app:layout_collapseMode="pin"` for that element. Perhaps this is in the `LinearLayout` or `ImageView`?

If the `LinearLayout` holds something else then you should add some scroll flags to that too, probably best would be `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"` if it is supposed to scroll off screen.

Lastly, make sure you are **not** disabling nested scrolling in your RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need wrap content in NestedScrollView and set `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` in NestedScrollView

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RecyclerView inside ViewPager then add this line to ViewPager: `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"`

It will solve your problem.